docker container can not save/mapping file folder to host
I have Node Server inside Docker, inside server, I have upload file function, which save file to /uploads.
Here is the success code which  help me make the file in this folder :
app.post('/uploadFile', upload.single('File'), (req, res) => {
    var tmp_path = req.file.path;
    var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.file.originalname;
    var src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
    src.pipe(dest);
    src.on('end', function () {
        fs.unlinkSync(tmp_path)
        res.redirect(`/${req.file.originalname}`)
    });

    src.on('error', function (err) {
        res.status(403).send(err.message)
    });
});

After upload file I check to container, and confirm this file has located here:

In the Dockerfile, I set the Worin
gDir as `/server/, then I used  Docker compose to run all:
Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8081 5433
CMD ["npm", "start"]

Docker compose:
server:
    image: **my build server**
    container_name: server
    platform: linux/amd64
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /uploads:/server/uploads
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db

In the host, I created uploads folder, then run docker compose up, but when uploaded file to server, I do not see those file inside host upload folder. Do I wrong?

Can someone help?

You're mounting to /uploads in the host's root directory. You probably meant ./uploads:/server/uploads

worked, thanks you. Please write a answer then I will mark it

It's just a typo, doesn't need an answer

(Also consider fixing the major security issue in constructing the file path: if the caller claims the file path is ../../etc/shadow, as your code is written, you're allowing an untrusted caller to overwrite arbitrary files in the container.)
